# svg with "non-scaling-stroke" ignores viewbox and uses its viewport

Tags: svg

I'm working with an SVG that I don't want the stroke of `<circle>` to scale when resized. What happens when I add `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` to the `<circle>` is that now the circumference becomes based on the **viewport** and not the original **viewBox**. This is a problem because when using `stroke-dasharray` for an animation, it's referencing the wrong circumference.

The following snippet shows a `stroke-dasharray` set to the circumference of two circles of the same size and the right circle showing the problem (using the viewport; effectively doubling its circumference):

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 6;
  stroke-dasharray: 252
}
```

```html
<body>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">

    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />

    <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="40" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />

  </svg>

</body>
```

Is there any way to tell the `<circle>` to respect the viewBox and not the viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when you specify non-scaling stroke: it's "not-scaling" the "dash" in the stroke as well as the stroke itself. If you had a normal stroke dash array (rather than using it as an animation hack) - this is the behavior you would want :) There is currently no way to specify a different coordinate system just for the dash-array calculation, so javascript is your friend.

Comment: I don't agree with your statement that this would be the desired behaviour. When you specify non-scaling-stroke, it is the width of the stroke that's effected, the length of the stroke is still being scaled. Since stroke-dasharray references the length of the stroke I would expect it to respect the scaling. As far as I'm concerned the described behaviour is a bug.

Comment: File bugs and/or request a spec clarification in SVG2 - it's still WIP.